# how to add element (or convert an Integer ArrayList) to an Integer Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, integer

here is what i have got

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer a = 50; 
    Integer b = 55;
    Integer c = 98;
    Integer d = 101;
    list.add(a);
    list.add(b);
    list.add(c);
    list.add(d);
```

now i want to convert this "list" to an Array...
e.g.:

```
Integer[] actual= {50,55,98,101};
```

anyway how to do it? thanks.

Comment: list.toArray(new Integer[0]);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```

If you want an `int[]` array, you'll have to loop over the list and unbox each element explicitly.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html next time you're looking for a method of List.

Comment: Apache [Commons Lang's](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [ArrayUtils.toPrimitive](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive(java.lang.Integer[])) methods can help converting between arrays of wrappers and arrays of primitives.

Answer (score 1):

Sefirosu, for another solution you can do it using `Arrays.copyOf()` or `Arrays.copyOfRange()` too.

```
Integer[] integerArray = Arrays.copyOf(list.toArray(), list.toArray().length, Integer[].class);
Integer[] integerArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(list.toArray(), 0, 4, Integer[].class);
```